# How to stop Fusion 360 from creating a new version on STL export

Tags: stl, fusion360

Everytime I export to STL in Fusion 360, a new Version (V1, V2, V3, V4, ...) of the file is created. But I would really like to use that feature to mark bigger changes instead of creating a new version everytime I change a minor detail to see how the Cura reacts to it.

For some reason, no new version gets created when I send the model to Cura via the tools tab. But then no new STL file gets created, but Fusion 360 opens a new instance of Cura instead. Even if Cura is already open.
That's not what I want. I want to overwrite the old STL file so Cura offers me to reload the STL file and I can keep working in the instance of Cura which is already open.

I already deactivated the checkbox to create a new version everytime I save the file. That settings works as expected

Comment: Ops, I meant the setting that creates new versions when I close, not when I save. As I understood it, clicking save is the action that actually should create a new version. But I just realized that setting doesn't work as expected either. So right now, it's not possible for me to close Fusion 360 without losing my work and without creating a new version.
But that's a different story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this will solve your issue directly for you but when I save a STL/3MF from F360 I don't use the File/Export in 360.

Instead I just right click the body in the browser tree and save the STL/3MF directly from that menu.
Select **"save as mesh"** This does not add any version number, and also the usage of cloud processing is not required so it's much faster.

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks, that solves my problem. Not the way you think, but it solves my problem.
I noticed this basically gives me the same window I get when I send the model directly to a slicer over the tools tab. The difference is, the checkbox to send it to a slicer isn't checked by default and a file gets created instead. Before, I didn't even realize this checkbox is there.
The way you describe also solves another problem. I can export multiple bodies as separate STL files. That will help me as soon as I start using the dual extrusion feature of the printer I just bought.